# Beego not accepting ajax params

Tags: ajax, go, vue.js, beego

I'm trying to make simple POST request using VueJS to an application which is written in Beego framework (GoLang) but the application doesn't see any input request. Everything is ok when I use standard form request (no ajax).
This is my VueJS code:

```
storePost: function(event) {
    axios.post("/api/posts/store", {body: "test"}).then(function(response) {
        if (response.data.status == 200) {
            this.posts.push(response.data.data);
        }else {
            console.log("error");
        }
    }, function(response){
        console.log("error");
    });
}
```

and this is my Beego code:

```
// router.go
beego.Router("/api/posts/store", &controllers_API.PostsController{}, "post:Store")

// PostsController.go
func (this *PostsController) Store() {
    fmt.Println(this.GetString("body"))

    // some irrelevant code which handles the response...
}
```

`fmt.Println` always prints nothing. When I use standard forms `fmt.Println` prints the value of the `body` with no problems.

Comment: can you see the payload traffic in network tab under developer tools? just to make sure there's actual data being sent to the server.

Comment: no beego expert, but it might be that a head method endpoint is also needed if you go cross domain

Comment: @Sombriks I checked, and there is data, {body: "test"}

Comment: @RickyA It's not cross domain, I'm testing it on localhost

Comment: on the same port?

Comment: @RickyA Yes, the VueJS application is rendered inside Go template, I'm bulding hybrid app, half is SPA and half is regular app. 
I've done this with PHP and it works great but can't implement it in Go

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Beego only accepts data with this header: `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` so after I added that header everything was ok.
Since I didn't know how to do that with `axios` I switched to `vue-resource` and this is the example code which works with Beego:

```
this.$http.post("/", {test: "test"}, {
    emulateJSON: true
});
```

Now you can print it like this:

```
fmt.Println(this.GetString("test"))
```

I hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Just verified that axios and vue-resource use `application/json` by default. The `emulateJSON` you use here [tells vue-resource to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/db9c0ccc9af812fd72c2e3ad7c7ce3a73b7f7b7f/docs/config.md#legacy-web-servers). You probably just need to do a json decode in beego because it by default treats request body as `urlencoded`.

`multipart/form-data` works probably because it's been there for long(like `urlencoded`) so beego by default recognizes it. To use vue-resource to post a `multipart/form-data` request: [use FormData](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/db9c0ccc9af812fd72c2e3ad7c7ce3a73b7f7b7f/docs/recipes.md#forms). [Axios also accepts a FormData as `data`](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#request-config).